# Stored values and echoed values different in php recursive function

Tags: php, recursion, echo

Hey guys this is making my head hurt.

I am writing a recursive function that will go through a directory of files to create an xml sitemap.

I have come across a problem in that if I echo out the value it shows exactly what I want, but if I store it (to then write the file at the end) the value is different.

```
function dirToArrayXML($dir, $langCode, $data)
{
    $result = array();
    $cdir = scandir($dir);
    $str = "";
    foreach ($cdir as $key => $value)
    {
        if (!in_array($value,array(".","..")))
        {
            if (is_dir($dir . "/" . $value))
            {
                $result[$value] = dirToArrayXML($dir . "/" . $value, $langCode, $data);
            }
            else
            {
                $result[] = $value;
                if(endsWith($value, ".php"))
                {
                    $page = substr($value, 0, -4);
                    $str .= "
    <url>
        <loc>http://www.example.com/".$dir."/".$page."</loc>
        <changefreq>monthly</changefreq>";

        echo "
        http://www.example.com/".$dir. "/".$page;
                    $languages2 = array("en","de","el","es","ru","tr");

                    foreach($languages2 as $lang2)
                    {
                        $jazz = substr($dir, 3);
                        $filepath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/".$lang2."/".$jazz."/".$page .".php";

                        if($langCode != $lang2)
                        {
                            if(file_exists($filepath))
                            {
                            echo "
            http://www.formacompany.com/".$lang2."/".$jazz."/".$page;
                            $str.="
        <xhtml:link rel=\"alternate\" hreflang=\"".$lang2."\" href=\"http://www.example.com/".$lang2."/".$jazz."/".$page ."\"/>";
                            }
                        }
                    }
                $str.="
    </url>";    
            $data.=$str;

                }  
            }
        }
    }
    return $data;
}
```

The outputted value in the file is

```
<url>
        <loc>http://www.example.com/ru/company-details</loc>
        <changefreq>monthly</changefreq>
        <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="http://www.example.com/en//company-details"/>
        <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="de" href="http://www.example.com/de//company-details"/>
        <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="es" href="http://www.example.com/es//company-details"/>
    </url>
```

Whereas the echoed values are

```
http://www.example.com/ru/folder/company-details
    http://www.example.com/en/folder/company-details
    http://www.example.com/de/folder/company-details
    http://www.example.com/ed/folder/company-details
```

Why are the values different? How can I get the stored values to match what is echoed?

Comment: You can make life easier for yourself by putting variables directly in your quoted strings and using single quotes around your attributes -- e.g. `$str .= "<xhtml:link rel='alternate' hreflang='$lang2' href='http://www.example.com/$lang2/$jazz/$page' />";`

Answer (score 0):

In your code you have this:

```
$str .= "
  <url>
    <loc>http://www.example.com/".$dir."/".$page."</loc>
    <changefreq>monthly</changefreq>";

echo "http://www.example.com/".$dir. "/".$page;
```

In several places, you set a different thing for the `$str` variable, while you `echo` out a different string.

Find all instances of `$str.=` where it sets the markup and just convert it so it only includes the string you want, ie:

```
$str .= "http://www.example.com/".$dir. "/".$page;
```

Comment: its does not explain why the $dir value is empty in $str but has a value in the echoed statement